# How do i use Regex in C# to extract @ViewData variable values from a cshtml page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, razor

I have the following cshtml page:

```
<div class="container ptb-60">
<div class="row featurette">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">@ViewData["PageTitle"]</h2>
        <p class="lead">@ViewData["Excerpt"]</p>
        <p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="@ViewData["Template.HeaderButton.Url"]" role="button">@ViewData["Template.HeaderButton.Text"]</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" src="@ViewData["Template.HeaderButton.Image"]" alt="@ViewData["Template.HeaderButton.AltText"]">
    </div>
</div>
```

and i want to extract all the variable values of @ViewData - so for this example i would like to get a matches list containing:

```
"PageTitle"
"Excerpt"
"Template.HeaderButton.Url"
"Template.HeaderButton.Text"
"Template.HeaderButton.Image"
"Template.HeaderButton.AltText"
```

My best effort so far was to use this: `Regex regex = new Regex(@"""[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*""");` to extract all string values (between speech marks) but this got confused with some values, i need to search for `@ViewData["GET_THIS_BIT_AS_A_MATCH"]`

Tried this: `@"""[^@ViewData\[""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\]\\]*)*"""`

But no luck! I am a bit of a RegeX noob!!! Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the values within @ViewData, I think this pattern will do what you need: `@ViewData\[\"(.*?)\"\]`. The value will be the capture group.